# Exception when using MapView - java.lang.RuntimeException: stub

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-maps

Does the following exception make sense to you? I'm struggling to identify the cause. It occurs when I open a an activity (ActivityMap) subclassed from MapActivity, even if the MapActivity's layout doesn't contain a mapview element.

I suspect it's a project issue. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. I've set the project up to build against the level 8 Maps API. The IDE is not highlighting any issues with my use of MapActivity in the source, and it builds without error - but then this exception at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:apiKey="<maps api key is here>"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then the activity:

```
public class ActivityMap extends MapActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitymap);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
    return super.isLocationDisplayed();
}
```

}

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.someapp.myapp/com.someapp.myapp.ActivityMap}: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
        at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.someapp.myapp.ActivityMap.<init>(ActivityMap.java:7)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Comment: are you sure you register your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, it is registered. This is not the exception I'd see if it wasn't though, and as soon as I change the activity to an Activity instead of a MapActivity, it works fine.

Comment: It's simply an activity derived from MapActivity, with no methods (apart from the two mandated). The evidence I'm seeing suggests strongly this is a build issue, not a procedural code issue (not least because there's almost no code)

Comment: is it a test project? or just a normal one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error usually occurs when running unit tests where the classpath also includes the Android JAR file (Android jar also contains junit test packages, junit.framework and junit.runner).

However, as you're not running any unit tests, the problem lmust be somewhere else.

A while back, I've written an article on how to integrate maps : http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/01/18/using-google-maps-in-your-android-app/

It covers all the steps required in detail, and some common errors people are having when integrating maps.

Comment: can you post all the dependencies you currently have in your project ?

Comment: the  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> element is present in your manifest right ? (inside the application tag).

Comment: <uses-library> was outside the <application> tag which moved me one step forward (to another exception). If you can add it as a new answer, and I'll mark it as the selected answer and add more detail.

Comment: Updated my answer. Included a link to a blog article I wrote that covers all the steps. Also common mistakes like you made (putting uses-library outside application tag) is mentioned. hopefully it will get you somewhere.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new exception you're getting ?

Comment: The new exception was a class not found exception re MapView. I've used MapView before, which is why this was so frustrating. but it turned out to be a project issue. IntelliJ IDEA had the maps APIs listed under both global libraries, and SDKs, and both were referenced in the dependencies. I tweaked the dependencies to only include one, and it now works fine. So the issue was not that MapView wasn't there, but was duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turned out it was caused by using the Android 3.0 libraries instead of the Google 3.0 APIs.

To change the library I simply right clicked on the project in Eclipse, selected Properties, under the Android option I selected the Google APIs (for 3.0) instead of the Android 3.0 library.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul have an api key in xml file of your map activity 
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: There is a Maps API key in the mapview in the layout, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok. I think you are having other problems. Maybe the Android Google Maps API. Try creating a new project. Have you done a map view before, and did it worked?

Comment: Yes, I've used Maps successfully before. As I said in my question I suspect it's a build/project related issue, but what?