# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo after adding google map functionality

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-mapview, android-maps

In my application , when I select the button, it will intent me on the mapView class, which shows me the current location of the user.

But, it throw

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity. ComponentInfo error
```

I have already added java class file in AndroidManifest file.

my xml file is as below ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my api key"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my java class is as below

```
package c.c.c;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MygoogleActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

my android Manifest file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="c.c.c" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MygoogleActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please be aware that publishing your map API key is not a good idea. I did replace it with "XXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception when using MapView - java.lang.RuntimeException: stub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912453/exception-when-using-mapview-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub)

Comment: this code is working properly if I run it seperately ,, but when I put it in my application it throws noclassDefinationFound error in logcat.

Comment: I think you need to move your `<uses-library/>` inside `<application/>` as shown in first answer. As a side note, code formatting is done with the `{}` button or 4 spaces indentation

Comment: I know that , and tried that , but still getting the error .

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the google maps user library in your AndroidMainfest file

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
          <activity>
                /**********/
          </activity>
 </application>
```

you need to provide internet permission also...

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: help me please , it really matters for me.

Comment: in xml file you have taken Relative layout but in java file at the time of binding you binded Linear Layout...... maybe that will be the error. once modify that & execute the code. in xml file change relative layout to linear layout & execute

Comment: just remove your linear layout in xml file & remove lineay layout in java file which you binded & run the code once. once thoroughly go through you Manifest file that did you registered all your files or not.

Comment: I have created the very short code ,,, still not getting the error